# FindEigen.cmake not found on Maverick only

Tags: ros, ros-release, eigen, rosdeb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to release a stack which depends on Eigen3 as a system dependency.
It works for all platforms on Electric/Unstable except Maverick where the CMake Eigen
macro is not found:

```
 [rosbuild] Building package walk_interfaces
 [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
    Could not find module FindEigen.cmake or a configuration file for package
    Eigen.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindEigen.cmake or set Eigen_DIR to the
directory containing a CMake configuration file for Eigen.  The file will
have one of the following names:

  EigenConfig.cmake
  eigen-config.cmake
```

Did anyone else encountered the same problem? Is there any issue with Eigen support on Maverick?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12552/findeigen.cmake-not-found-on-maverick-only/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I receive the same error message with Electric under Oneiric if I do not have a FindEigen.cmake file. See the instructions here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen

However, I notice that recently there has been an odd edit to the wiki page that doesn't make sense. Here is a link to a good version in the history:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen?action=recall&rev=59

---

Originally posted by [Andrew Chambers](https://answers.ros.org/users/435/andrew-chambers/) with karma: 96 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-02-01**:
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki was indeed wrong (and was assuming Fuerte only), please follow the latest.
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen)

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3